# Auto scroll the DataGridView does not work when AllowUserToAddRows = false

Tags: c#, datagridview, autoscroll

I want to **DataGridView** only display data(readonly), and the user can not enter data through datagridview directly, but rather through the **DataSource** and **DataMember**. To prevent users enter data, I did set:

> m_dView.AllowUserToAddRows = false;

Why after set it, the DataGridView Auto Scroll does not work?

```
m_dView.DataSource = ds;
m_dView.DataMember = dm;
m_dView.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
m_dView.MultiSelect = false;
m_dView.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
m_dView.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;
m_dView.ReadOnly = true;
m_dView.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
m_dView.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
m_dView.AllowUserToOrderColumns = false;
m_dView.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;
m_dView.AllowUserToResizeColumns = false;
m_dView.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.DisableResizing;
m_dView.AllowUserToResizeRows = false;
m_dView.RowHeadersWidthSizeMode = DataGridViewRowHeadersWidthSizeMode.DisableResizing;

// auto scroll only worked only when m_dView.AllowUserToAddRows = true;
if (m_dView.Rows.Count > 0) {
    m_dView.CurrentCell = m_dView.Rows[m_dView.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[0];
}
```

Comment: Can you try out the sample I provided?

Comment: I tried everything, but nothing worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a code sample as shown below and it works perfectly.
Dragged and dropped a datagridview control on a new form as shown below and named it m_dView

Created a button which when clicked I run the code sample below

```
using (SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=deno;Trusted_Connection=True;"))
            {
                c.Open();

                using (SqlDataAdapter a = new SqlDataAdapter(
                    "SELECT * FROM test", c))
                {
                    // 3
                    // Use DataAdapter to fill DataTable
                    string dm = "TestScroll";
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    a.Fill(ds, dm);
                    // 4
                    // Render data onto the screen
                    m_dView.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
                    m_dView.DataSource = ds;
                    m_dView.DataMember = dm;
                    m_dView.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
                    m_dView.MultiSelect = false;
                    m_dView.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
                    m_dView.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;
                    m_dView.ReadOnly = true;
                    m_dView.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
                    m_dView.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
                    m_dView.AllowUserToOrderColumns = false;
                    m_dView.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;
                    m_dView.AllowUserToResizeColumns = false;
                    m_dView.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.DisableResizing;
                    m_dView.AllowUserToResizeRows = false;
                    m_dView.RowHeadersWidthSizeMode = DataGridViewRowHeadersWidthSizeMode.DisableResizing;

                }
                m_dView.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = m_dView.Rows.Count-1;
            }
```

I have scrolled the gridview to the last row using the [DataGridView.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.firstdisplayedscrollingrowindex.aspx) Property

for example

```
m_dView.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = m_dView.Rows.Count-1;
```

Can you copy and paste the following code to a new project and test? It could be some other problem that is the real culprit.

Comment: Thank you. I tried with m_dView.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = m_dView.Rows.Count - 1; but same result, auto scroll does not work.

Comment: Can you try FirstDisplayedCell option?

Comment: I'm tried with m_dView.FirstDisplayedCell = m_dView.CurrentCell; but same scrooll, still does not work.

Comment: Auto scroll only worked only when m_dView.AllowUserToAddRows = true; m_dView.CurrentCell = m_dView.Rows[m_dView.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[0]; but problems arise when users do click on the last row in DataGridView, error will be appear.

Comment: Did you try the full code sample I sent you? The code you posted works fine for me

Comment: Thank you. I discovered my mistake, I should call the autoscroll procedure shortly after the data is entered into the datagridview. Autoscroll running normally despite AllowUserToAddRows = false.

Comment: Its good to hear that things worked out for you :). Can you upvote this post if you found that it helped you?